# C - Gdb doesn't let me see values in stack memory

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, stack

I'm reading a book and to practice with C and assembly I'm using this simple script to analyse the functioning of memory:

```
void test_function(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
   int flag;
   char buffer[10];

   flag = 31337;
   buffer[0] = 'A';
}

int main() {
   test_function(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

This is the gdb output. I have intel disassembly-flavor and 64 bit system

```
(gdb) break 10
Breakpoint 1 at 0x67e: file stack_example.c, line 10.
(gdb) break test_function
Breakpoint 2 at 0x649: file stack_example.c, line 1.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/ut/Desktop/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at stack_example.c:10
10     test_function(1, 2, 3, 4);
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, test_function (a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4) at stack_example.c:1
1   void test_function(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
(gdb) disass test_function
Dump of assembler code for function test_function:
   0x0000555555554635 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000555555554636 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000555555554639 <+4>: sub    rsp,0x30
   0x000055555555463d <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x24],edi
   0x0000555555554640 <+11>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x28],esi
   0x0000555555554643 <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x2c],edx
   0x0000555555554646 <+17>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x30],ecx
=> 0x0000555555554649 <+20>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x0000555555554652 <+29>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x0000555555554656 <+33>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x0000555555554658 <+35>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],0x7a69
   0x000055555555465f <+42>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x12],0x41
   0x0000555555554663 <+46>:    nop
   0x0000555555554664 <+47>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x0000555555554668 <+51>:    xor    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x0000555555554671 <+60>:    je     0x555555554678 <test_function+67>
   0x0000555555554673 <+62>:    call   0x555555554540 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x0000555555554678 <+67>:    leave  
   0x0000555555554679 <+68>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/16xg $rsp
0x7fffffffe850: 0x0000000300000004  0x0000000100000002
0x7fffffffe860: 0x00007ffff7de72c0  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffe870: 0x00005555555546a0  0x0000555555554550
0x7fffffffe880: 0x00007fffffffe890  0x0000555555554697
0x7fffffffe890: 0x00005555555546a0  0x00007ffff7a3f06b
0x7fffffffe8a0: 0x0000000000000000  0x00007fffffffe978
0x7fffffffe8b0: 0x0000000100100000  0x000055555555467a
0x7fffffffe8c0: 0x0000000000000000  0x3a50765db3702ef3
```

Following the book, thanks to the last command in gdb, I should be able to see the 4 initial int in the last memory addresses. Also I should see, before these int, the other values of "flag" and "buffer", but I can't. In what am I wrong? How can I see the values?

And also, why would I use "16"? And why the $rsp? The values shouldn't be in $rbp?

Comment: The four values are right there. They're 32bit values, displayed within two 64 bit values. `0x0000000300000004 ` is 3,4, and `0x0000000100000002` is 1,2. Maybe change your dump to display as 32bit values (which will make the next value, the return address, look a little odd, but you don't seem interested in that right now).

Comment: Note also that the stack grows *downward* on most platforms, so the top of the stack is at the lowest addresses, which are printed first in your memory listing.

Comment: I feel stupid that I didn't notice them. That's because in the book I'm reading they are at the end, and I was only watching  at the end. Last thing, why does this values are 32 bit values? That's for something in particular?

Comment: They are 32-bit values because that's the size of an `int` on your C implementation.  C does not specify exactly what that size must be, but 32 bits is a very common choice on both 32-bit and 64-bit hardware.

Comment: Yeah, now I understand. Int is 4 bytes. 1 byte is 8 bit. 4X8=32. Thanks

Comment: But why would I use "16"? And why the $rsp? Shouldn't the values be in $rbp that is memory of local variables?

Comment: `mov    rbp,rsp` copies value of `rsp` to `rbp`, then after that there is `rsp -= 0x30`, so the values are relative to each other (+-0x30) (until some other instruction will modify one of them, like the `call`, `leave` or `ret` in your listing (all of them affecting `rsp` value).  ... also `rsp` is the "stack pointer" used implicitly by instructions like `call` or `push`, while `rbp` is [almost] general purpose register, and if you modify your C compiler options to not use "frame pointer", it will omit that code modifying `rbp`, and it may contain some completely unrelated value.

Comment: when you say call, leave, ret affect rsp value, I don't understand why. For example here: `DWORD PTR [rbp-0x28],esi` they work on rbp, not rsp

Comment: Because that's how they work, did you check, what they do and how? The `call` "will put return address to stack", which means in 64b mode something like `rsp -= 8, [rsp] = rip, rip = call_argument`: there, `rsp` is smaller by 8 after `call` instruction (I mean inside the code which was called, if you "step-over" `call`, then that is neutralized by `ret`, which pops the return address from stack back into `rip` and adds 8 to `rsp`). If you will switch off the frame pointer, the C compiler will generate those debug memory writes probably through `rip` directly.

Comment: although this is unoptimized code, so it may still use `rbp` for convenience and speed of compilation, hard to say, I usually don't check unoptimized code, so I'm not sure what kind of stunts the compiler does there, in real world usually you need to check only the optimized code, which in your case would mean empty `ret` function, not putting into stack anything except the return address (and would you change that function to local only, it would be inlined and optimized into nothing, as it does nothing).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177826/discussion-between-allexj-and-ped7g).

Answer (score 0):

This is line where is your values : 0x7fffffffe850: 0x0000000300000004  0x0000000100000002 , and your program put on the stack in this way (like any C use stack).

Try:

```
(gdb) x/10 &buffer
```

or

```
(gdb) x/s buffer
```